# Narrowing the range of an interpolating function while keeping integral the same?

Tags: function-construction, interpolation, expression-manipulation

Consider an interpolating function derived from some data, e.g.

```
data = Table[{x, Cos[2 π/1000 x] // N}, {x, -250, 250}];
fun[x_] = Piecewise[{{Interpolation[data][x], Min[data[[;; , 1]]] <= x <= Max[data[[;; , 1]]]}}]
```

As it is, the interpolation shows a hump that goes to zero at `x=-250` and `x=250`:

```
Plot[fun[x], {x, -500, 500}]
```

[image]

Now I would like to change (manipulate) the interpolation function such that e.g. the function goes to zero at `x=-100` and `x=100` instead while the hight increases proportionally such as to keep the integral constant

```
Integrate[fun[x],{x,-Infinity,Infinity}]
```

> 318.31

Here a rough sketch how the result should look like
[image]

How can I do this with mathematica?

EDIT:

Naively, I could always do

```
targetA = NIntegrate[fun[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];
transfA = NIntegrate[fun[x 5/2.], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];
newfun[x_] = fun[x 5/2] targetA/transfA;
Plot[{fun[x], newfun[x]}, {x, -500, 500}]
```

[image]

But I wonder if there is a less pedestrian way of doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The area under your curve is

```
Integrate[Cos[2 Pi/1000 x],{x,-250,250}]==1000/Pi
```

Scale your curve by a factor `s`

```
s=4;
Integrate[s*Cos[2 Pi/1000 x/s],{x,-250/s,250/s}]==1000/Pi
```

and that will hold for any positive value of s.

Comment: Note that `Cos` is chosen for convenience here, to illustrate the point. In actual application the data does not follow a known function.

Comment: For your unknown function does scaling down the horizontal extent by a factor of s and scaling up the vertical extent by a factor of s still yield the same area? For sufficiently nice functions that should be true. It might be amusing to try to find functions where that does not hold.

Comment: Oh, I see! That is a good point, I'll check.

Comment: Oh, in fact, $\int dx f(x)=a\int dy f(a y)$ for $x=ay$ makes total sense for anything smooth! You're right, my question is kind of silly, this should work most of the time (and indeed it works for the relevant data).

Comment: I want to be VERY clear. I was NOT being critical of you or your question or implying that it was in any way silly. We sometimes get so wrapped up in grinding through the calculus or through the programming that we sometimes miss the insight and understanding that lies hidden just below the surface.

Comment: Thank you Bill for your kind words, I was being a bit self-critical there. Sorry if it sounded a bit like I was reading it into your words, it was just a manner of speech. I was hoping the oxford-like comma after "you are right" would sufficiently separate it from "my question is silly", as in agreeing with you and then concluding separately for myself that my question is silly. ^^